# How to deploy a metro app to windows 8 device/Tablet?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

For testing an application, I have deployed my metro app by creating a app package which is provided in vs2012. I have deployed the package by opening using the PowerShell, but now I want to deploy the metro app in a Windows 8 device (tablet) for testing it, how can I do this?

1. Will there be a PowerShell option available in device also?  (to deploy the app)
2. Are there any other ways of deployment?

Answer (score 4):

i have used this to sideload apps for testing onto other devices including SurfaceRT
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2012/11/06/10365947.aspx

Comment: first of all thanks for the reply , you mean to say that run using powershell option is avaliable in windows tablet or other windows 8 deivces also?

Comment: installation / sideloading is possible as long as you have the relevant files. The install scripts will get the device license etc as needed.

Comment: This answer could really use some details as it is currently a link-only.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to creating an app package in Visual Studio 2012, and deploying your app that way, you can also use the [Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2012 for ARM](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9810474) to deploy and debug an app to a Surface or other tablet (for x86 or x64 tablets, use the matching remote tools install).

Once the remote tools have been installed on the target device, you simply start up the remote tools on the target, configure the access permissions, and then on your development machine, open the project properties, select the Debugging option, and use the dropdown to select Remote Machine as the debugger to launch. Click into the Machine Name field, and use the dropdown to select the machine name of the target machine running the remote tools.

Now, when you start debugging the project, it'll be packaged up and deployed to the target device, and you can set breakpoints and step through your code. And once deployed this way, you can re-run the app from the start screen using the app's tile.

EDIT: One important thing to note...whether you deploy/sideload using the PowerShell script technique, or using remote debugging, the target device will need to have a valid developer license. You should be prompted to obtain a developer license when you attempt to sideload your app, but you can also use PowerShell to obtain the license manually...instructions can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh974578.aspx

Comment: This is easier way to debug than side-loading, I think!