# How to test the developed app in Windows 8 RT

Tags: windows-8, windows-rt

Recently I had developed a C#/XAML METRO Application, I created the package which generated the `Add-AppDevPackage.ps1` and all other files from VS2012.

How to deploy this package in real device for testing in Surface RT tablet?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30703

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deploy a metro app to windows 8 device/Tablet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378484/how-to-deploy-a-metro-app-to-windows-8-device-tablet)

Answer (score 1):

Right click on "Add-AppDevPackage.ps1", select "Run with powershell". Follow the instructions in powershell. Please note you must be admin. If you are prompt for developer licence login with Live a/c.